# How do you recover assets from an account that is no longer accessible?

Tags: support, accounts

I have an old account that is blocked because the google account associated with it is deleted. How can you merge the reputation from those accounts into my new account, and declare the questions asked on my old account owned by my new account? Thanks for any help.

Comment: And select the How to merge duplicate accounts dropdown

Comment: Goto contact and select merge duplicate. That's the whole answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can contact stackoverflow team at https://stackoverflow.com/contact and select the "I need to merge user profiles" dropdown.

Or if your email is deleted, you could do this: click on other, then describe your problem.

Comment: Wait, when I did that, I have gotten this message:

`Thanks for submitting your merge request!

You should receive two emails, one for each profile. Please click the confirmation link in each email to complete the merge.

If you don't receive the emails, please get in touch with us by selecting 'Other' on the contact form`

But I can't access my other email account!

Comment: @Ender Oh, then click on other.